# Dynamically add DotNetNuke tokens to url

Tags: email, token, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

Is it possible to add a user's email at the end of a external link in a DotNetNuke site? Basically, I want it to appear like this:

http://www.website.com/?U=myemail@domain.com

With *myemail@domain.com* to change to the user's email.

I tried using the DNN token, [User:Email], within the Page Management settings, but the token doesn't populate. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to to this would be via [DNNSharp's MyTokens module](http://www.dnnsharp.com/dnn/modules/my-custom-tokens).

Another approach would be to use token replacement in an HTML module, storing the user's email address in a div that is not displayed.  Then, use jQuery to grab it and add it to the link.